# Is it possible to share a folder for writes and updates between different IPFS nodes?

Tags: ipfs

Is it possible to share a folder for writes and updates between different IPFS nodes?

Sample scenario:
There are 10 IPFS nodes, which are writing files into a single shared directory (same pin). 
Node #1 can not change/remove other node's files. All nodes can read all files.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect [IPFS Cluster](https://cluster.ipfs.io) may be what you are looking for:

> IPFS Cluster provides data orchestration across a swarm of IPFS daemons by allocating, replicating and tracking a global pinset distributed among multiple peers.

By default it assumes all nodes are trusted.

If you prefer to have "leader" (read-write) and "follower" (read only) nodes, there is *Collaborative Clusters* feature: https://cluster.ipfs.io/documentation/collaborative/